# Getting error while run migrate command in laravel 8

Tags: php, migration, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I'm using `Laravel Cashier` package.

I've added below line AppServiceProvider.php > boot method

```
 Cashier::ignoreMigrations();
```

I've create my own migration i.e: create_subscriptions_table and create_subscription_items_table

When I run `php artisan migrate` command then getting below error:

```
   Migrating: 2019_05_03_000002_create_subscriptions_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'subscriptions' already exists (SQL: create table `subscriptions` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `name` varchar(191) not null, `stripe_id` varchar(191) not null, `stripe_status` varchar(191) not null, `stripe_plan` varchar(191) null, `quantity` int null, `trial_ends_at` timestamp null, `ends_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I get this error because migration `2019_05_03_000002_create_subscriptions_table` is in vendor folder.

I want run my own migration not from vendor so is there any solution to fix this issue ?

Comment: After you add ```Cashier::ignoreMigrations();``` in AppServiceProvider, you dropped all tabled and re-run migration? Or just run ```php artisan migrate```?

Comment: I've run php artisan migrate command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed issue by following steps:

1. First I run command `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-migrations"`. It will create a new migrations and I've removed code of up() and down() method from new migrations.

By doing this we can keep our override migration of Cashier package.

2. Run command `php artisan migrate`